# How does the Hard Light Sword's damage scale with gun marks?

Tags: dead-cells

The Hard Light Sword's description says it "Deals critical damage depending on the number of gun marks on the target". How exactly does the damage scaling work? How much extra damage gets dealt per gun mark?

[image: Hard Light Sword description]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Dead Cells fandom wiki](https://deadcells.fandom.com/wiki/Hard_Light_Sword):

> The critical damage is calculated by multiplying the normal damage by a certain multiplier, which is determined by how many marks an enemy has.
> Damage multiplier is 1.1/1.5/1.7/1.9/2.2/2.5 for 1 to 6 marks respectively.